# How get subscribe to user flag on a node

Tags: flags, message-subscribe

1. I have a node for example news
2. I have [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module installed
3. I've enabled the flag subscribe to user

I want people to be able to subscriber to
a user. To get updates on thier latest post.

4. I want to add the subscriber user flag to the node template for

This is what flag module suggests to do

[Placing a flag link on a page](https://www.drupal.org/node/295383)

```
$account = menu_get_object('user');   
print flag_create_link('fools', $account->uid);
```

How would I add this to a node?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a block with a php filter or create a custom template for that node. You can also alter that node from from template.php

http://www.webomelette.com/altering-node-content-it%E2%80%99s-rendered-page-drupal-7

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.